# changes using boto3 for connections to aws services

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore

What all changes has to be done while using a function which was using boto2 earlier and how has to be changes to **boto3** below is one such function example which is on boto2  and it needs to be changed to boto3

```
def aws(serviceName, module=boto):
    conn = connections.get(serviceName)
    if conn is None:
        service = getattr(module, serviceName)
        conn = service.connect_to_region(region)
        connections[serviceName] = conn
    return conn
```

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't seem to be doing much. It is simply connecting to an AWS service.

The boto3 equivalent is probably:

```
client = boto3.client(serviceName)
```

The region can be defined in the standard `.aws/config` file, or as:

```
client = boto3.client(serviceName, region_name='ap-southeast-2')
```

I recently converted some code from `boto` to `boto3` and every line pretty much needed changing. The result, however, was a lot cleaner.

It is also worth trying to understand the difference between:

- `boto3` client: Makes normal API calls to AWS
- `boto3` resource: A higher-level set of objects that make it easier to interact with resources, rather than using standard API calls (eg `vpc.subnets()` vs `describe-subnets(VPC=xxx)`)

---

The original code block appears to be storing its information in a `connections` array (defined elsewhere) for re-use. Therefore, the equivalent code block would be:

```
def aws(serviceName):
    conn = connections.get(serviceName)
    if conn is None:
        conn = boto3.client(serviceName, region)
        connections[serviceName] = conn
    return conn
```

Comment: but can u help to get the exact commands that i can use  for this function for boto3

Comment: What does the function actually _do_? Can you provide sample code that _uses_ the function so we can figure out a purpose? It seems to be heap of nothing.

Comment: below is one such function where its being used to list the stacks                    `def get_all_stacks():
  # start with a empty cache again
    persist = get_persist_dict()
    cfn = aws('cloudformation')
    next_token = None
    all_stacks = []
    while True:
        stacks = cfn.describe_stacks(next_token=next_token)
        next_token = stacks.next_token
        all_stacks += list(stacks)

        if not next_token:
            break `

Comment: I've added a code block that would _seem_ to be doing the same thing. The original code references `connections` and `region`, which I can only assume are globally-defined variables. The code block is basically storing and re-using connections, or creating new ones if they don't previously exist.

Comment: @ John Rotenstein Still getting the exceptions while listing the stacks                                         
    ` File "cloudstacks.py", line 132, in aws
    conn = boto3.client(serviceName, region)                                                                        File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 137, in _endpoint_for_partition
    if region_name in service_data['endpoints']:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'  `